Combine flows but always wait for one to emit
I have 3 source kotlin flows that are periodically emitting values. I have one collector that collects 2 of these flows by combining and calculating a certain value. This calculated value is also emitted in a separate intermediate flow. Something like the following:
val intermediateFlow = combine(mySourceFlow1, mySourceFlow2, ::Pair).transform {
    val result = calculateResult(it)
    emit(result)
} 

I then have another collector that collects the source flows as well as the intermediateFlow above. In a sense, I have a dependency of one collector towards the other one. What I want to achieve, is for this collector to be executed when one of the source flows emits, but I always want to make sure that this collector will use the up-to-date value from the intermediateFlow. So if intermediateFlow needs to calculate and emit a new value, then the dependent collector must wait for it before executing itself. If it doesn't need to calculate a new value, then the dependent collector must also know that it is okay to use the old emitted value. This is what I came up with so far:
val combinedSourceFlows = combine(mySourceFlow2, mySourceFlow3, ::Pair)
combinedSourceFlows
  .zip(intermediateFlow, ::Pair)
  .collect { (source, intermediate) -> 
      // do some work here
  }

This will work for the happy path when both the source flow and intermediate flow emit values. However, if only one of them emit, the zip block will not be triggered. combine operator would also not solve my problem, because I want to make sure that I use the up-to-date value from intermediateFlow.
How can I achieve the desired behavior with existing operators? Or maybe there is another mechanism that should be used here that I am not aware of? I would appreciate some interesting ideas.
